# HTML relative URLs function in non-standard way

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to move a customers website to a new host.
I moved the code but the links don't work.

the directory structure is

```
/root /About Us  
/root/Contacts
```

The code has the form

```
<a href="/about/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
```

This should not  work because the preceding slash in /about/ is not standard html but it works.

`<a href="/about/"` should be `<a href="about/"`.
All the hmtl is wrapped in index.php files.

The original site is hosted on rackspace and I am testing the code on my local apache server.

Is there some configuration file that changes the way relative addressing works.

Comment: The question makes so sense because those are not "relative" links... they are "absolute".  I'm not sure what you're trying to describe but you should at least mention or post the contents of your `htaccess` file if you're going to tag your question as such.

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand what the question is. *Shouldn't* it work? *Doesn't* it work? These are *standard absolute* URLs, not *non-standard relative* URLs.

Comment: I am confused that the linking system works on the rackspace server but the same link code does not work on my server.  If I remove the preceeding slash from <a href="/about/" it works.

Comment: The two servers simply have a different "base" starting points (www document root)... is why it works on one but not the other.  In other words, the leading `/` represents a different starting point on the second server.

Answer (score 4):

To quickly get it working on your local server, just add a `<base>` tag to the head.

```
<base href="http://localhost/my_site_folder/" />
```

Hyperlinks work in one of the ways:

- (absolute) If the link starts with a protocol (http://, https://,
  etc), your browser tries to open the literal url.
- (root-relative) If the link starts with a forward slash, it prepends the current domain to the url.
  (if you're anywhere on www.topcompanies.com, `<a href="/about">` will take you to http://www.topcompanies.com/about
  This style url will fail if you move your site to a subfolder.
- (relative) Otherwise, the link is treated as relative to the current "folder".  This style url will work correctly if you move your entire site - however, if you move an .html file to a different depth in the directory structure, it will cease to link correctly.

When you add a `<base>` tag to the head, it'll tell the browser to use that url as the base for root-relative urls, not the normal http root.

Answer (score 0):

Relative addressing is what it is and ditto absolute.  Either

- You need to do a bulk change to your code / html to massage hrefs to the correct form, or
- You need to research how to do URI rewriting. At an application level, this would typically be done using `.htaccess` files and the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module. If necessary move the app to a separate subdomain, and then use a vhost config or mod_rewrite rule based on **HTTP_HOST** filtering.

PS. I've added the tags that are relevant.